# remember button clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code behind on a web page and am trying to get the output to display into the listbox as

1 + 1 = 2

The problem I am having is remembering the operation button pressed and adding that to the listbox. The current output is

1 ButtonSave 1 = 2

ButtonSave being the last button clicked

```
namespace calcpage
{
   public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
      protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) && 
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text))
            TextBox3.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text) +
            Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text)).ToString();
        Label3.Text = string.Empty;
        ViewState["LastButtonClicked"] = ButtonAdd.ID;
      }

      protected void ButtonSub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text))
            TextBox3.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text) -
            Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text)).ToString();
         Label3.Text = string.Empty;
         ViewState["LastButtonClicked"] = ButtonSub.ID;
      }

      protected void ButtonMul_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) && 
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text))
            TextBox3.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text) *
            Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text)).ToString();
         Label3.Text = string.Empty;
         ViewState["LastButtonClicked"] = ButtonMul.ID;
      }

      protected void ButtonDiv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         try
         {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) && 
               !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text))
               TextBox3.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text) / 
               Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text)).ToString();
               ViewState["LastButtonClicked"] = ButtonDiv.ID;
         }
         catch
         {
            if (TextBox2.Text == "0")
            {
               TextBox3.Text = string.Empty;
               Label3.Text = "You can't divide by 0, try another number";
            }
         }
      }         

      protected void ButtonReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         TextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
         TextBox2.Text = string.Empty;
         TextBox3.Text = string.Empty;
         Label3.Text = string.Empty;
      }

      protected void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         var lastButtonClicked = (string)ViewState["LastButtonClicked"];

         if (ListBox1.Items.Count < 10)
         {
            ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text + (" ") + lastButtonClicked + 
            (" ") + TextBox2.Text + (" ") + ("=") + (" ") + TextBox3.Text);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Your title has been edited. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: In your `ButtonSave_Click` event, try using `clickedButton.Text` instead of `clickedButton.ID`

Comment: That tweak did it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the view state.  It's used to persist any state between requests.

Set it here

```
ViewState["LastButtonClicked"] = someButton.Id;
```

Get it here

```
var lastButtonClicked = (string)ViewState["LastButtonClicked"];
```

Comment: I have this working, though it's now showing (for the case of addition) 1 ButtonAdd 1 = 2. I updated the original question with your advice.